# Multiple Account for MobileStore?

Tags: app-store, ovistore

If you are handling the release of a program for a client, do you need to create an account for each one or can you use your account and just change the copyright/editor/stuff like that on a per app basis ?

On AppStore it seems that the owner of the account is automaticaly shown in the editor section.

I didn't find anywhere where you could change it. So I was wondering if it was the same for ovistore ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the same for Ovi!